# Update an Item from a List in Sharepoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Let's say I have two lists, `List A` and `List B`.

`List A` has a field named `Quantity A`.

`List B` has a field named `Quantity B`.

I want to create a **workflow** on `List A` that, **when I add a new Item in `List A`**, updates the value of `Quantity B` from `List B` like this: **`Quantity B = Quantity B - Quantity A`**.

**Is that possible using Sharepoint Designer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

Use the workflow action to update a list item. Follow the dialog. You will need to identify the list and the list item that you want to update, but it's pretty straightforward.

Edit: Use the "Update List Item" action. Click `this list`. Select the list you want to update. Click `Add` and add the fields you want to update.

In the "Find the List Item" section select the field you want to use for identifying the correct item, for example the ID field. In the Value box enter what the value of the field needs to be, for example 3 for the item with ID 3.

Click OK.

Comment: Can you please explain me a little bit in detail? Thank you

Comment: I added some more details.